# Reporting images not found to my webserver

Tags: javascript, tomcat

I would like a high level suggestion on how to get individuals loading my page to report back to the webserver (tomcat) that images have not been loaded.

Note: the images would be from another server which I have no control over.

The goal is to know when an image is no longer available.

Javascript and XMLHttRequests seems to be what I will try to do, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler or better way.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the client feedback to remove images from your site may be "dangerous" as besides the obvious possibility of somebody evil just exploiting this and remove all images from your site this way, one could simply turn images off, experience a timeout to a specific server due to various reasons or have an adblocker/firewall blocking the specific domain.

The proper way to do this is to periodically do a `HEAD` request from your server to the source server and check if you get a `200` back.